# Fire Javascript (or Google Tag Manager Tag) on 2nd Page User Visits

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I would like to fire javascript (a popup form) on the 2nd page a user visits on our website.

Do I need to store a pageview value within the dataLayer and then create a trigger based on that value? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally this is what you'd use a cookie for.

Comment: You can use cookie, local storage or session storage for this type of behavior.